# Why is context.getImageData() throwing cross domain exceptions for me on an https address?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, https, cross-domain

I've got a canvas element on my website which, for some users, is throwing cross domain exceptions. The issue has occurred in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but I've been unable to replicate it myself in any browser.

The console output from Chrome is:

`Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin 
data.`

The error is thrown by the library [StackBlur.js](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlur.js), where it calls `imageData = context.getImageData( top_x, top_y, width, height );`

However, the images used on the site are all on the same domain, protocol and port. The paths are generated by Rails. The main path is like `https://myappp.com/` and the image paths are like `https://myapp.com/assets/promo/slideshow/slides/myslideimage.jpg`

Deploying the exact same code on our staging site (which does not use HTTPS) `http://staging.myapp.com/` with image paths like `http://myapp.com/assets/promo/slideshow/slides/myslideimage.jpg` results in no errors.

Why might the use of HTTPS be causing cross-domain issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mostly mistaken. It turns out that our redirect from http to https was on the blink, so a user was able to visit the http version with assets from https, meaning that the error was entirely legitimate all along. I never reproduced it because I visited the site from my browser history, which was https.

Fixing our redirect so both the main request and assets are on the same protocol resolves the issue.